# White flash of screen in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal.app

Apparently I've configured some kind of utility that makes my whole screen flash white whenever my Terminal.app gives a 'bell'. This is not the same as the option "visual bell" on the preference pane of Terminal. Does anyone know how I can deactivate this behavior? It's pretty annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have the “flash the screen on alerts” hearing assistance feature turned on.

Try searching for “flash screen” in *System Preferences* (it should be in the Universal Access preference pane, probably under Hearing).

Comment: Not a clue how i turned that on, but that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Edit your `~/.inputrc` and set readline variable `bell-style` to `none`:

```
set bell-style none
```